# resolving the pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

In the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{

   double *p= (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*5);
   double *s= (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));

   printf("Enter first value: "); scanf("%lf",p);
   printf("\nEnter 2nd value: "); scanf("%lf",p+1);
   printf("\nEnter 3rd value: "); scanf("%lf",p+2);

   printf("\n\ntable is:\n");
   printf("1st value %f\taddress: %p\n",*p,p);
   printf("2nd value %f\taddress: %p\n",*(p+1),(p+1));
   printf("3rd value %f\taddress: %p\n",*(p+2),(p+2));
   printf("\n\n\nvalue %f\taddress: %p\n",*s,s);

return 0;}
```

Now suppose that the pointer **p** contains the hex value 00BD0D50. But the address obtained from when i use **p+1** , will give the hex value. 00BD0D58. 
Why there is this gap of 00000008 between these values even when only 1 is added to **p**'s value ?

> I tried using **%d** in place of **%p** to output pointer's value but still it had a difference of 8.

And if there is some reason behind it, is there any other way to access a value at address lying between this gap of 00000008 bytes? ( for example in above case, is there any way to access value at 00BD0D51 ?)

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `sizeof(double)`?

Comment: Oh, and you *do* know that the expression `*(p + i)` is equivalent to `p[i]`?

Comment: Furthermore, when you print the value of `*s` you have *undefined behavior*. The `malloc` function doesn't initialize the memory it allocates, so its contents will be *indeterminate*. Using uninitialized data (except to initialize it) leads to UB (Undefined Behavior).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why there is this gap of 00000008 between these values even when only
>   1 is added to p's value ?

Because size of double type is 8 bytes presumably on your machine. That is called pointer arithmetic. So when you add 1 to the pointer, in reality 8 bytes are added to it due to size of pointee.

> is there any other way to access a value at address lying between this
>   gap of 00000008 bytes?

Yes you need to cast the pointer say to `char *` before doing the pointer arithmetic.

PS. Also you have undefined behaviour when trying to print value of `*s` - because it has not been initialized.

Also when using `%p` format specifier you need to cast the pointer to `void*` in `printf`, e.g.

```
 printf("1st value %f\taddress: %p\n",*p, (void*) p);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pointer arithmetic! `p+1` is the address of the next `double` in memory. As your `double`s  are 8 bytes long, so is `p+1`.